# How do I make all navigation links look the same?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigationbar

I wanted to make the navigation links shown in the in screenshot have the same padding all around them, regardless of the text length (my professor said something about "justify", I do not exactly remember what though). Also, I want to have the menu stretch only up until a certain width, after that it should stay the same size.

Navigation links showing padding problem on first link:

[image: Navigation links]

This is the html of the navigation links:

```
<nav id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="nav-intro" href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-cont" href="#content">My Shoes</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-loc" href="locations">Where I buy from</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-care" href="care">Proper Care</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the CSS of the navigation links:

```css
nav a {
    background-color: #280e0e;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #C70039;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.444em;
    padding-top: 0.444em;
    align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-width: 18.889em; 
}

nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is the media query for my navigation links:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 484px){
    nav ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0 -0.25em;
    }

    nav ul li {
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin: 0 0.25em;
        padding-left: 0.333em;
        padding-right: 0.333em;
    }
```

This is for a school project, and I have to use only CSS to edit how everything looks. I would like to continue using flexbox, and not change to anything else.

Comment: [Recommended guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Advait Joshi You have to adjust padding and margin accordingly in order to achieve this. I have made some edits and here the link.
https://jsfiddle.net/reddysridhar53/yf9jm832/9/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with this, but it extends the boxes just slightly.

```css
nav a {
  background-color: #280e0e;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #C70039;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 0.444em;
  padding-top: 0.444em;
  align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 18.889em;
  height: 40px;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 484px) {
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 -0.25em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0 0.25em;
    padding-left: 0.333em;
    padding-right: 0.333em;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="nav-intro" href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-cont" href="#content">My Shoes</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-loc" href="locations">Where I buy from</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-care" href="care">Proper Care</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Above I included a snippet, but you can see it working in [codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQGJPR).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Nav menu</title>
 <style>

  ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   display: flex; 
  }
  nav ul li {
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 11px;
   margin: 10px 10px;
  }
  nav a {
   background-color: #280e0e;
      border-radius: 15px;
      color: #C70039;
      display: block;
      word-break: normal;
      white-space: pre;
      font-size: 1.25em;
      padding-bottom: 0.444em;
      padding-top: 0.444em;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      max-width: 18.889em;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <nav id="navigation">
   <ul>
     <li><a id="nav-intro" href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
     <li><a id="nav-cont" href="#content">My Shoes</a></li>
     <li><a id="nav-loc" href="locations">Where I buy from</a></li>
     <li><a id="nav-care" href="care">Proper Care</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```